# How can Facebook verify Facebook Connect requests?

Tags: javascript, facebook, api, sdk

So I'm developing my own API for my website - I'm mimicking the Facebook JS SDK in regards to how my system works. API client displays a button, popup comes up and the user can log in. Login popup issues an event to the opener window and the parent window now knows the user is logged in. That all works.

What I'm having trouble understanding is how they can verify that the refresh requests are valid. If the API client needs to send a request to the server to ask if the user is logged in and it's all in JS, then everything is transparent. The API client says, "Hi, I'm application 4jhkk2l3bnm389, is the user that's logged in on Facebook also authenticated with me? If so, can you send me a new token so I can make API calls?" and Facebook says, "Oh, you're application 4jhkk2l3bnm389? Yeah, the user is logged in and has allowed you to access their information, here's an access token."

But how does Facebook prevent an outside application that isn't the authentic application from saying, "Hey, *I'M* actually application 4jhkk2l3bnm389, I promise I'm not lying. Can I have an access token?"

I have no idea how they determine the difference. Obviously if it was all done through AJAX calls in modern browsers then you could just provide an Access-Control-Allow-Origin header. But if a malicious client were to use cURL then I don't think I could ever tell the difference. How does Facebook do it? A good explanation is much appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All access tokens belongs to an app/user pair, and in order for Facebook to return such an access token to the app, these has to be verified.

The app, or client_id, is verified against the domain specified in the redirect_uri - if the page tries to use a client_id/redirect_uri pair it does not own, then it will not receive the access token as this will be passed to the valid redirect_uri (the mechanism the JS SDK uses follows the same rule).

The user, or uid, is verified using the cookie Facebook sets when you sign in.

While you can easily spoof the client_id/redirect_uri pair using curl, the same does not apply to the uid, as you would have to be in the possession of the users cookie. And if this is the case, well, then you could simply grant your own application access.

Comment: Thank you very much for this. So I suppose the best way to go about all this is to have the API client set a "refresh cookie" on their server that represents the user in some way. When the user reloads the page, the client checks to see if that cookie exists. If it does, it redirects to the auth gateway and then redirects to the callback page with a token (provided the refresh cookie was correct.) Makes sense to me! Thanks a lot.

Comment: Actually by this logic I could do it by AJAX then couldn't I? Save the refresh cookie when the user authorizes the client, call it on each page load, and change it on each page load.

Comment: @iLoch Do what by AJAX? XMLHttpRequest is subject to the same Same-Origin Policy as the rest of the browser, and CORS is not enabled for such endpoints.

Comment: OAuth and authentication in general is not for the light-hearted - I suggest you do not try this alone if you are not fully comfortable with cookies, identity claims and so forth :)

Comment: Essentially I'd issue a long standing auth token to the API client when the user authenticates their account with that API client. The API client then automatically saves this cookie (via my API) to their site, so whenever the user goes to their site they can pull that token from the users cookies and load their information from my site. The token changes every time a request is made on the user's behalf in order to avoid unauthorized calls by the API client. As for the Same-Origin policy, the API client has a domain whitelist, if the domain is in that list, I allow AJAX calls from that domain

Answer (score 0):

Facebook uses [OAuth 2.0](http://oauth.net/2/) for authentication.  You can find details of how Facebook deals with OAuth right here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/.  There are many different ways OAuth can be used, depending on whether you're on a mobile device, a page on facebook.com itself, or, in your case, just a web page outside of facebook.com.  The details of that final flow can be found here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/client-side/.

Basically, Facebook knows what applications you have given permission to view your information.  When you run one of those applications, they first make sure you are logged in to Facebook, then they request a user access token from Facebook, essentially saying, "Hey Facebook, I don't know this person, nor should I.  Can I get access to their information?".  And then Facebook looks internally and if it decides this particular application should have access to this user's information, it sends a user token.

That's the simple way of describing it.  There are many different ways the authentication flow can happen, depending as I said earlier on what kind of device the request is happening from, whether this is a page on facebook.com, etc., essentially based on your security constraints.  Best to read the Facebook authentication docs referred to earlier for the details since it can get quite tricky.

Comment: I'll take a look at those links, but I sort of feel you missed my question - perhaps I wasn't wording it well enough. The question, on a most basic level is, how does Facebook prevent scripts from spoofing application IDs if they don't need a client secret to authenticate through the JS API?